# user spell checking on certain text area even if the browser's is off

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I am using jsf 2.1 I need a plugin or a way with javascript to spell check text in a certain text area even if the user disabled the spell-checking feature from his browser.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any way to spell check it doesn't have to be javascript

Answer (score 0):

Go visit http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/. I think this can help you. I have tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: I am trying to use it right now but it is used for php and asp.net,and I am using none of them

Comment: Did you mean that you need a way to integrate jsf and javascript ?

Comment: I mean this plugin is for php or asp would it also work with jsf easly?

Comment: I did not think about compatibility problems because the version which you are using is pretty new.

Comment: it didn't work, the text area view changed and the popup window shows nothing